# I am making a Discord SelfBot in Python and getting an error for a mute command

Tags: python, discord

I am making a Discord SelfBot in Python and I am getting this one error for a mute command that is confusing to me.

This is the code for the mute command

```
@commands.command(name="mute", description="Mute a user from the command server.", usage=" [@member] (reason)")
    async def mute(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason="Undefined"):
        if ctx.author.guild_permissions.mute_members:
            mutedRole = get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
            await member.add_roles(mutedRole)
```

This is where the error is and I can't seem to fix it

```
mutedRole = get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
```

This is what it says when I hover over the error part

```
[pyflakes] undefined name 'get'
```

And when I take "get" away it gives me an error under

```
name="Muted")
```

Saying

```
[pyflakes] invalid syntax
```

[Error With 'get'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Itqh.png)

[Error without 'get'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqiMX.png)

Comment: Have you imported get from discord.utils?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment of **Ceres** here is a possbile answer:

You want to use `get` but it seems like you never "imported" it. To overcome the errors you get you have to import the following:

```py
from discord.utils import get
```

I also noticed that you are using`reason` but don't insert it in your code.

**A possible complete code would be:**

```py
from discord.utils import get # Import get to get the role

@commands.command(name="mute", description="Mute a user from the command server.", usage=" [@member] (reason)")
    async def mute(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason="Undefined"):
        if ctx.author.guild_permissions.mute_members:
            mutedRole = get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
            await member.add_roles(mutedRole, reason=reason) # Add reason
```

For more information look at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get#discord.utils.get)